# AVCaptureSession with Singleton. How to manage?

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, avfoundation, avcapturesession

So guys, as I have multiple views and some zooming buttons that I need them to change the preview camera output, I think it will be correctly to use *Singleton* for Session initialization, but I have no idea how to do that, and can't find any good information, could someone help me please?

Comment: Create a class with singleton, and have the property for the AVCaptureSession. You can even use this http://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton to create singleton.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

okay, so, I managed somehow to write it, I don't know if it's okay, here is the code:

```
protocol Singleton: class {
static var sharedInstance: Self { get }
}


final class AVFSessionSingleton: Singleton {
static let sharedInstance = AVFSessionSingleton()
private init() {
    session = newVideoCaptureSession()!
}


var session: AVCaptureSession!
var imageOutput : AVCaptureStillImageOutput?

//FUNCTION

func newVideoCaptureSession () -> AVCaptureSession? {

    func initCaptureDevice() -> AVCaptureDevice? {
        var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
        let devices: NSArray = AVCaptureDevice.devices() as NSArray

        for device: Any in devices {
            if (device as AnyObject).position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back {
                captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
            }
        }
        print("device inited")
        return captureDevice
    }

    func initOutput() {
        self.imageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    }

    func initInputDevice(captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice) -> AVCaptureInput? {
        var deviceInput : AVCaptureInput?
        do {
            deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
        }
        catch _ {
            deviceInput = nil
        }
        return deviceInput
    }

    func initSession(deviceInput: AVCaptureInput) {
        self.session = AVCaptureSession()
        self.session?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
        self.session?.addInput(deviceInput)
        self.session?.addOutput(self.imageOutput!)
    }

    return session
 }

}
```

So now I want to call it in that way I can manage the layouts for a Preview, any suggestions please?....